# Allocating unused space to root?

Tags: partitioning, disk, disk-management

I'm trying to manage a server that constantly is running out of space. when i run lsblk i get the results below. 
Seems to me theres alot of free unused disk space, and only 5GB is allocated to root.

Can i allocate this safely to the root partition somehow from the terminal without risking loss of any data?

[image: lsblk results]

[image: df results]

Comment: Note that you have an LVM here, not real partitions. You would have to grow the `rm--stat01--vg-root` logical volume, not alter any partitions.